# WearOS 3.5 onSensorChanged not called for Step Counter and Heart Rate

Tags: java, wear-os

Google Pixel 7 running WearOS 3.5.  The SensorEventListener isn't behaving as expected.  I've registered listeners for the step counter, heart rate, and accelerometer.  Only the accelerometer triggers onSensorChanged.

The prototype I'm building is attempting to sample heart rate and steps then send them to an API.

Someone put me out of my misery please and steer me in the right direction.  Is there something obvious I am missing?  Anyone else have a WearOS 3.5 device handy and feel like having a quick hack to confirm if this works or not?

```
private class WatchFaceEngine extends CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine implements SensorEventListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    ...
    
    mStepSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
    mHeartRateSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE);
    mAccelerationSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerationSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mStepSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mHeartRateSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    
    ...

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) {
        mStepCount = (int) event.values[0];
    } else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE) {
        float mHeartRateFloat = event.values[0];
        mPulseCount = Math.round(mHeartRateFloat);
    }
}

...
```

**AndroidManifest.xml permissions**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BODY_SENSORS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Confirming this code works on WearOS 3.5.  After a bit more digging I found my app permissions were not set correctly.  As soon as I allowed Receive Complication Data, Sensors, and Physical Activity permissions everything works fine.